# Error to populate CI's Dropdown (form_helper)

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

This is my attempt to try to populate CI's dropdown (using the from helper):

```
foreach ($freetables as $t) :
    $tableNo          = $t['tableNo'];                  
    $tableDescription = $t['description1'];

    $data=array($tableNo=>$tableDescription1);
endforeach;

print_r($data);

//echo form_dropdown('table',$data,$this->session->userData('queueNo'));
echo form_dropdown('table',$data);
```

However I can only see the last item in dropdown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$data` array is being overwritten at each iteration, here: `$data=array($tableNo=>$tableDescription1);`

This solution assumes `tableno` is unique, and the *value* attribute is to be the `tableno` with `description1` as the corresponding option. (And it avoids the overwriting issue!).

```
foreach ($freetables as $t)
{
    $data[$t['tableNo']] = $t['description1'];
}

echo form_dropdown('table', $data);
```

Comment: final , print_r result >> 
Array ( [001] => Table1 [002] => Table2 [003] => Table3 [004] => Table4 [005] => Table5 [006] => Table6 )